# communication between activity class and java class

Tags: android

i have one java file and one activity class file. in the activity class i have one Textview. how can i change the textview text from my java class

```
public void sendMessageforstatus(String status)
{
        if(status.contains("Door is open"))
        {

                ds.updatedoor("open");

        }

        else if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Door is close"))
        {
               ds.updatedoor("close");

        }
}
```

this is the logic in java file now i want to update the text in the Textview which is in another activity class

```
public void sendMessageforstatus(String status)
{
    if(status.contains("Door is open"))
    {


        tdoor.setText("OPEN");
    }

    else if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Door is close"))
    {

        tdoor.setText("CLOSE");
    }
```

this is code method in activity class , but when iam trying this one iam getting NULLpointerException...

can u plzz help me?

Comment: Not knowing how your non-Activity class exists in yoru design/architecture, we can't really answer your question. Also, all classes are Java classes.

Comment: try using an interface object

Comment: You are getting a NullPointerException because something is not initialized. Probably because you can't just "access views of an Activity" directly from other classes.

Comment: Let the Activity class take care of the UI and the "business logic" class take care of the business logic. I think that below you are getting some bad advice in the answers suggesting to mess around with the UI from the business logic code. The "logic" class could just call a method in the Activity class to let the Activity know what needs to be updated and how on the UI. Then if you later change your UI, you don't need to modify your business logic class as it is "UI agnostic". (Yes, I know this is all trivial and elementary, but worth mentioning.)

Answer (score 0):

Make the textview  abstract and try this code from the java class

```
activityname.textviewname.setText("blahblah");
```

Answer (score 0):

pass `TextView` to your Java class and then you can use it inside.